# How to make my dropdown menu work over two lines?

Tags: html, css

My dropdown menu, lifted a few years ago from a long-lost online resource, works fine on a full-sized screen.  I keep it as a separate html file and then include that file on each page on the site, so I only have to modify one file when the site changes.

When the screen width is reduced, the menu drops to two lines.  No problem with that, but when you hover over the top line, you can't access the menu items - as soon as you move the cursor down, you hover over a button from the second line and *that* menu then shows.  You can see for yourself what I mean [here](http://m.miramodus.com/test.shtml).
I've tried several solutions from answers to similar questions, but with no success.  If anyone has any pointers for workable solutions, I'd be extremely grateful.  Thanks!

The page calls a CSS file, of which the relevant code is:

```
ul, ol {
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
dd { margin: 0 0 0 40px; }
nav ul, nav ol { list-style: none; list-style-image: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

The relevant code from the dropdown menu file is:

```
<style>
ul a{display:block; color:#333; text-decoration:none; line-height:32px; width:110px; padding:0 15px; text-align:center }
ul li{  position:relative;  float:left; margin:0;   padding:0}
ul li a:link{
    background: #000000;
    color: #BAE7E7
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/Tab_background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 110px;
}
ul ul{  display:none;   position:absolute;  top:100%;   left:0; background:#fff; padding:0}
ul ul li{   float:none; width:110px}
ul ul a{    line-height:120%;   padding:10px 15px}
ul ul ul{   top:0;  left:100%}
ul{ list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

<!--ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(file:///C|/Dreamweaver_websites/pictures/Tab_background.jpg);
    color: #FFF;
}
The hilite code-->
body.home  ul li a:link.home,
body.about ul li a:link.about,
body.services u l li a:link.services,
body.products ul li a:link.products,
body.contact ul li a:link.contact {
   background-color: #000 ;  }
a:link {
    color: #80FFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #81BBF5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #3F9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #0CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}


</style>
</head>
<body link="#82BCFD" class="link">
<DIV>
<ul>
<li><a href="Home.shtml">Miramodus </a></li>
  <li ><a href="ourmodels.shtml">Our Models</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="range.shtml">Range</a></li>
      <li><a href="Examples.shtml">Examples</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="teaching_models.shtml">Teaching molecular models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Inorganic_structure_models.shtml">Inorganic structure models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Inorganic_molecular_models.shtml">Inorganic molecular models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Mineral_structure_models.shtml">Mineral structure models</a></li>
              <li><a href="organic_molecular models.shtml">Biological and Organic Molecular Models</a></li>
              <li><a href="maths.shtml">Mathematical models</a></li>
              <li><a href="crystallography_models.shtml">Crystallographic models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Protein_models.shtml">Protein molecular models</a></li>
           </ul>  </li>
      <li><a href="Standard_colours.shtml">Colours</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Colour selector</a>
      <li><a href="price_estimator.php">Price estimator</a>
    </ul>
  </li>  


  <li><a href="Standard_models.shtml">Standard models</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Alphabetic_index.shtml">Alphabetic list</a></li>
      <li><a href="Search_database.php">Search catalogue</a></li>
      <li><a href="Protein_models.shtml">Proteins</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li> 


   <li><a href="Custom_built_molecular_models.shtml">Custom Builds</a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="extra_features.shtml">Extra features</a></li>
          <li><a href="3d_printed.shtml">3d Printed Models</a></li>
          <li><a href="brass_molecular_models.shtml">Brass molecular models</a></li>
          <li><a href="Perspex_molecular_models.shtml">Perspex molecular models</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>


  <li><a href="Giant_molecular_models.shtml">Giant Models</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="static_giant_molecular_models.shtml">Static models</a></li>
      <li><a href="Detachable_giant_molecular_models.shtml">Detachable models</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other large models</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>


<li><a class="contact" href="Contact_form.shtml">Contact Us</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="Contact_form.shtml">Contact form</a></li>
      <li><a href="Aboutus.shtml">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact_information.shtml">Contact information</a></li>
      <li><a href="ordering.shtml">Ordering</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="Order_form.shtml">Order form</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Pay online</a>
             <li><a href="terms.shtml">Terms</a>
           </ul>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `z-index:1;` to below UL as shown below also check updated code snippet:

```
ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  z-index:1;/*newly added*/
}
```

```css
ul a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 32px;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

ul li a:link {
  background: #000000;
  color: #BAE7E7
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-image: url(images/Tab_background.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width: 110px;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  z-index:1;
}

ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 110px
}

ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px
}

ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

<!--ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: url(file:///C|/Dreamweaver_websites/pictures/Tab_background.jpg);
  color: #FFF;
}

The hilite code-->body.home ul li a:link.home,
body.about ul li a:link.about,
body.services u l li a:link.services,
body.products ul li a:link.products,
body.contact ul li a:link.contact {
  background-color: #000;
}

a:link {
  color: #80FFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #81BBF5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #3F9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: #0CC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body link="#82BCFD" class="link">
  <DIV>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Home.shtml">Miramodus </a></li>
      <li><a href="ourmodels.shtml">Our Models</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="range.shtml">Range</a></li>
          <li><a href="Examples.shtml">Examples</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="teaching_models.shtml">Teaching molecular models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Inorganic_structure_models.shtml">Inorganic structure models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Inorganic_molecular_models.shtml">Inorganic molecular models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Mineral_structure_models.shtml">Mineral structure models</a></li>
              <li><a href="organic_molecular models.shtml">Biological and Organic Molecular Models</a></li>
              <li><a href="maths.shtml">Mathematical models</a></li>
              <li><a href="crystallography_models.shtml">Crystallographic models</a></li>
              <li><a href="Protein_models.shtml">Protein molecular models</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Standard_colours.shtml">Colours</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Colour selector</a>
            <li><a href="price_estimator.php">Price estimator</a>
        </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="Standard_models.shtml">Standard models</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Alphabetic_index.shtml">Alphabetic list</a></li>
            <li><a href="Search_database.php">Search catalogue</a></li>
            <li><a href="Protein_models.shtml">Proteins</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="Custom_built_molecular_models.shtml">Custom Builds</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="extra_features.shtml">Extra features</a></li>
            <li><a href="3d_printed.shtml">3d Printed Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="brass_molecular_models.shtml">Brass molecular models</a></li>
            <li><a href="Perspex_molecular_models.shtml">Perspex molecular models</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="Giant_molecular_models.shtml">Giant Models</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="static_giant_molecular_models.shtml">Static models</a></li>
            <li><a href="Detachable_giant_molecular_models.shtml">Detachable models</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other large models</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a class="contact" href="Contact_form.shtml">Contact Us</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Contact_form.shtml">Contact form</a></li>
            <li><a href="Aboutus.shtml">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact_information.shtml">Contact information</a></li>
            <li><a href="ordering.shtml">Ordering</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="Order_form.shtml">Order form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pay online</a>
                  <li><a href="terms.shtml">Terms</a>
              </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
          </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vikas, you are a star - VERY many thanks for that solution, which very definitely works!

Comment: @GavinW if it works for you please accept the answer ;)